# Construct continuous function and compute partial derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, derivatives

> Given $a,b\in \mathbb R$, prove that there is a continuous function $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ such that
>   $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} axy & \lvert y \rvert < \frac{1}{2} \lvert x \rvert \\ bxy & \lvert y \rvert > 2 \lvert x \rvert \end{cases}.$$ Show that $f$ has two partial derivatives in $(x,y) = (0,0)$ and compute them.

I think I have done the most but I am unsure if my solution is correct. I tried to construct a function defined as above on the specified regions, set $f(x,y) = 0$ whenever $\lvert x \rvert = \lvert y \rvert$ and "interpolate" in between: Define $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ by
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} axy & \lvert y \rvert < \frac{1}{2} \lvert x \rvert \\ bxy & \lvert y \lvert > 2 \lvert x\rvert  \\ 2axy(1-\frac{\lvert y \rvert }{\lvert x \rvert }) & \lvert x \rvert > \lvert y\rvert > \frac{1}{2}\lvert x \rvert\\ 2bxy(1 - \frac{\lvert x\rvert }{\lvert y \rvert}) & \lvert x \rvert < \lvert y \rvert < 2 \lvert x \rvert   \\ 0 & \lvert x \rvert = \lvert y  \rvert \end{cases}.$$
Then many calculations show that $f$ is indeed continuous on all of $\mathbb R$ (does this work? Is there a more "canonical" approach?) . Now I want to calculate the partial derivatives:
$$\partial_x f(0,0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(he_1) - f(0,0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{0}{h} = 0$$
and $$\partial_y f(0,0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(he_2) - f(0,0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{0}{h} = 0.$$
Now we see that $f$ also admits partial derivatives in the regions $\lvert y \rvert < \frac{1}{2} \lvert x \rvert$ and $\lvert y \rvert > 2 \lvert x \rvert $ with $\partial_xf(x,y) = ay$ and $\partial_y f(x,y) = bx$. Hence,
$$\partial_x^2 f(0,0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\partial_x f(he_1) - \partial_x f(0,0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{0}{h} = 0$$ as well as $$\partial_y^2 f(0,0) = 0. $$ But for the mixed derivatives one has
$$\partial_x \partial_yf(0,0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\partial_y f(he_1)- \partial_y f(0,0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{hb}{h} = b$$ and $$\partial_y \partial_x f(0,0) = a.$$
Are my computations correct? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your choice of $f(x,y)$ is indeed continuous - but there are infinitely many continuous $f$ which satisfy the condition in the question.

Note that the values of $f(h,0)$ and $f(0,h)$ for $h>0$ do not depend on the value of $f$ in the region $\frac{1}2|x|\le|y|\le 2x$.
The partial derivatives $\partial_x f$ and $\partial_y f$ are therefore zero irrespective of the function $f$ which is chosen.

You have just proved that $\partial_x\partial_y f \ne \partial_y\partial_x f$ at $(0,0)$ for any choice of $f$. As a consequence of [Clairaut's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Clairaut.27s_theorem), $f$ cannot have continuous second derivatives at the point $(0,0)$.

Comment: Is there any more "canonical" way to extend $f$ to a continuous function on all of $\mathbb R^2$?